# Append an <i> tag to entity field view hook

Tags: hooks

On a field of field type = LINK and widget = LINK, I want to add an  tag on the rendered output.

The reason is to be able to add a class, not to the whole  tag output, but to append a FontAwesome icon.

Hook_page_alter, of course shows all of the rendered HTML. I really don't want to mess with that.

I tried hook_entity_view_alter. That works in a clumsy fashion but two problems:

1) It only affects the output from the node displayed via a view
2) It appends the  tag in new  after the displayed link.

It appends the  tag in new  after the displayed link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can theme individual fields: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7

You can either have a theme function in template.php or a `tpl.php` template file, the former is preferred for performance reasons.

Using a theme function you could do something like:

```php
THEMENAME_field__link($vars) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($vars['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $link = l($item['#title'], $item['#href']);
    $output .= '<div class="' . $vars['classes'] . '"' . $vars['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . $link . '<i class="fa fa-download">&nbsp;</></div>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Though you'll have to check `$vars` for specifics.  As for checking the widget I think you can get a clue from `$vars['element']['#formatter']`

Comment: Given the configuration I had, this is the best answer. However, due to some other requirements, I finally gave in to using Display Suite (which I swore I would never do again). Side note: to my surprise, this new version of DS is a far cry from what I learned to hate with Drupal 6 and early versions for Drupal 7.  It still add a significant overhead, but worth it, in this case.

Comment: @user908998 I'd be reluctant to go that route as it seems like having that stuff in the db really muddies the whole separation of concerns thing but I understand sometimes you just need to get it done.